# Increasing size of checkbox in Safari with webkit transform scale

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, scale

My goal is to increase the size of the checkboxes, cross-browser. I have accomplished this goal in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome by using the browser prefixes (-moz-, -ms-, etc.) with this:

```
input[type=checkbox]
{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  -ms-transform: scale(2.1, 2.1); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2.1, 2.1); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.1, 2.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2.1, 2.1); /* Opera */
}
```

It is not working in Safari (and Opera, but I'm more focused on Safari). I have version 5.7.1 and I am accessing it from a windows desktop.

However, I was playing around with this jsfiddle and noticed that the scale works on divs: 
http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/KKVXB/

I stripped out the code to get the minimum that will still get the desired result:

```
<div class="matrix3d"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="opt1" id="option1" />

input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3,3); /* safari and chrome */   
}
.matrix3d {
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1); /* safari and chrome */
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/3xr7Q/

The checkbox is larger as expected, but as soon as I took out the 'matrix3d' class or alter the 'matrix3d' html or css in any way, the checkbox goes back to its normal size.

Does anyone know why it works with the 'matrix3d' class and how I can accomplish the goal without it, preferably by not editing the HTML? I do not want to just add an extra 'matrix3d' div next to my checkbox because I don't know why it affects the checkbox.

Edit: Also, something I notice is if I refresh the page, it flashes to the big size before going back to the small size. Also, it would nice to figure out it on Windows, but if someone says it works on a Mac or iphone, that might be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Input elements are inline not block level elements, and webkit has historically not supported transforms on inline elements.

One way to fix this is to add a display: inline-block to the input's CSS. I'm not an a Mac right now, so can't check this.